# Powershell WMI get software older than 30 days

Tags: powershell, filter, wmi, wql

i'm trying to get all software updates from configMgr in WMI, that are older than 30 days, i just cant seem to figure it out.

Timeformat in WMI is : DateRevised  : 20121113180000.000000+000

I tried the following :

```
$Date30DaysAgo = (get-date).AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyymmddHHMMSS")

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_PS1" -Class SMS_SoftwareUpdate -ComputerName SRVSCCM01 -Filter {"DateRevised <= '$($Date30DaysAgo)%'"}
```

This is working, but i need to get it working, with `-Filter` and not `where-object`

```
$Date30DaysAgo = (get-date).AddDays(-30)

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_PS1" -Class SMS_SoftwareUpdate -ComputerName SRVSCCM01 | Where-Object {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.DateRevised) -lt $Date30DaysAgo }
```

It's probably because i cant get the time conversion and the WQL less than operator to work.. can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put $Date30DaysAgo in WMI timestamp format using:

```
$Date30DaysAgo = ([wmi]"").ConvertFromDateTime((get-date).AddDays(-30))
```

or use

```
$Date30DaysAgo = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime(((get-date).AddDays(-30)).ToUniversalTime())
```

and use that value in your filter